# How do I find object based on child populated property on mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new in mongoose.
I have a Schema like this:

```
const sessionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  createdBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  registers: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Register',
    },
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    immutable: true,
  },
});
```

And register model is this one:

```
const registerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  sets: [
    {
      weight: {
        type: Number,
      },
      weightUnit: {
        type: String,
        default: 'kg',
      },
      repetitions: {
        type: Number,
      },
      duration: {
        type: Number,
      },
    },
  ],
  session: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Session',
  },
  exercise: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Exercise',
  },
  creationDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    immutable: true,
  },
});
```

I want to find all the sessions created by a user and has an register with an specificied exercise id. I tried this:

```
const result = Session.find({createdBy: userId, 'registers.exercise': exerciseId}).populate('registers');
```

But doesn't work. ¿Any suggestion?

Thanks :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Session.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { createdBy: userId }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'Register',
      localField: 'registers',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'registers'
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { 'registers.exercise': exerciseId }
  }
])
.then((result) => {
  console.log('Result: ', result);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Error: ', err);
});
```

If you are not familiar with MongoDB aggregation framework, the query above might be a bit foreign to you. However, for cross collection queries like you described in your question, the aggregation framework is your best shot(for now).

The `$match` is basically doing what you would do with a `Model.find()`, while the `$lookup` is doing what you would do with a `Model.<query>.populate()`

You can read more about MongoDB aggregation framework [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).